# Lambda into a method

Tags: c#, lambda, streamreader

I have a method where I'm reading a textfile. 
I have to get the words in the textfile which start with "ART".

I have a foreach loop which loops through the method.

```
class ProductsList
{
public static void Main()
{
    String path = @"D:\ProductsProjects\products.txt";
    GetProducts(path,  s => s.StartsWith("ART"));
    //foreach (String productin GetProducts(path, s => s.StartsWith("ART"))) 
    //Console.Write("{0}; ", word);

}
```

My method looks like this:

```
public static String GetProducts(String path, Func<String, bool> lambda)
{
    try {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)){
            string[] products= sr.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
            // need to get all the products starting with ART
            foreach (string s in products){
                return s;
            }

        }
    }

     catch (IOException ioe){
        Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        }
        return ="";
        }

    }
```

I'm having problems with the lambda in the method, I'm new to working with lambda's and I don't really know how to apply the lambda in the method.

I'm sorry if I can't really explain myself that well.

Comment: `foreach(var s in products) { return s; }` will only ever return the first item. Is that what you want? If so why not just do `return products.First(/* some lambda */)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong in that it only ever returns the one string, you want to return multiple strings, if the list of products is large this could also take a while, I'd recommend doing it this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetProducts(string path, Func<string, bool> matcher)
{
    using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            do
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (matcher(line)) yield return line
            }while(!reader.EndOfFile)
        }
    }
}
```

Then using it is as simple as:

```
foreach(var product in GetProducts("abc.txt", s => s.StartsWith("ART")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a matching product: {0}", product);
}
```

This code has the benefit of returning all of the lines that match the predicate (the lambda), as well as doing so using an iterator block, which means it doesn't actually read the next line until you ask for it.

Comment: Then it may be `EndOfStream` I wrote it by hand in notepad, so some things may not be completely right, you need to explore the code and not just copy & paste it.

Comment: I'd already had it edited to EndOfStream, but yet it doesn't show me any of the results.  I've got a test textfile with ART1 ART2 and noART  in it.

Comment: @Elvira you have to **enumerate** the collection, try doing a `.ToList()` call on the `IEnumerable<string>` result returned by the method: `var products = GetProducts("abc.txt").ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

just add it here

```
foreach (string s in products.Where(lambda))
```

**Update:**

you should change your method like this to return a list of products and not just a single

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetProducts(String path, Func<String, bool> lambda)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string[] products = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
        // need to get all the products starting with ART
        foreach (string s in products.Where(lambda))
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when I uncomment the  //foreach (String product in GetProducts(path, s => s.StartsWith("ART"))) 
    //Console.Write("{0}; ", product); I'm having this error: Can't convert type char to string

Comment: What's the point in using an iterator block here if the underlying data has been completely fetched already?

Comment: i just wanted to keep elviras code - this would be my approach: `File.ReadAllText(@"D:\ProductsProjects\products.txt").Split(' ').Where(s => s.StartsWith("ART")).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write("{0}; ", x));`

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried it yet, but I will try it out later and I will let you know if it works :)